# Is there an easy/shortcut way to obtain visualizations of basic stats of any dataframe in python?

Tags: python, dataframe, plot, jupyter-notebook, plotly

I am trying to find out if there is an easy way or like a one line code to plot the basic statistics (like mean, std dev, min, max etc) of any dataframe in python using plotly or any such graphing library. Right now I made a few functions to manipulate the dataframe, to transform it into a desired form containing basic stats so I can plot it using cufflinks. And I get the basic stats of all columns in a dataframe, in one place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, You can try Pandas plot() method, matplotlib, and Seaborn. Seaborn syntax are very simple and offers attractive and informative statistical graphics. 
Pandas: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html 
Seaborn Examples: https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/index.html

For interactive visualization, you can use Plotly and Altair.
Altair Examples: https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/index.html

Comment: thank u for this! i found a few interesting plots in altair, like box pot for min/max, interactive average or bar chart line at mean for average; it is a great collection of charts!

Comment: Hi @Aishwarya If you liked my answer then why downvoted it. what exactly you want?

Comment: hi @Avinash i didnt downvote it, in fact i upvoted it multiple times just now, my downvote or upvotes are not displayed publicly because my reputation is less than 15, i hope the confusion is cleared :)  someone else has downvoted your solution, and the other solution to this question too, i think they deleted their answers they posted here

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to use the `.plot()` method on a dataframe you're working with and be returned a collection of different types of graphs.

Comment: thank u so much for the input, .plot is from matplotlib, I think a plotly chart would be better as it is interactive